# use of "dedicated to"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, phrase-meaning

I want to seek more clarification on the use of "dedicated to". Understand that dedicate means someone devoting time/effort to a project/research/work (i.e. dedicate his time to studying 18 hours a day), can I use "dedicated to" in replacement of "assigned to"? Please see example below.

"This sheet contains their preliminary assumption on the time dedicated to each employee on the project"

Thanks

Comment: I feel that using 'dedicated to' in that context implies that 'they' are spending their time with the employee, rather than indicating an amount of time the employee has spent on the project.  An example: lawyers bill by the hour and will fill out time sheets for the amount of hours they have dedicated to a certain client.

Comment: The entire sentences is awkward and difficult to understand. Do you mean something like the following? *The spreadsheet lists the estimates of time each employee will spend on the project.* (If it makes sense, you can replace my use of *spend on* with *dedicate to*.)